# Beamer presentation: Fixed position of Block in the second column

Tags: beamer, columns, block

I have a frame which i devide it in 2 columns. The first one for an image.The second one for some blocks:

```
\begin{frame}
 \frametitle{Buoy design}
  \begin{columns}
    \column{0.38\textwidth}
 \includegraphics[scale=0.48]{figures/Results/BuoyDesign}
 \column{0.62\textwidth}
 \onslide<1-3>{
  \begin{block}{Equation of Motion}
 \[
 [\underline{M}+\underline{A}]\ddot{x}(t)+\underline{k}x(t)= F(t)
\]
\end{block}}
\only<2>{
\begin{block}{Mass Matrix M}
 \[
 \begin{bmatrix}M_{tot}&M_{tot}z_g&0&0\\M_{tot}z_g&I_{xx}&0&0\\0&0&M_{tot}&M_{tot}z_g\\0&0&M_{tot}z_g&I_{yy}\end{bmatrix}
 \]

 \end{block}
}
\only<3>{
\begin{block}{Added Mass Matrix A}
   \[
     \begin{bmatrix}  A_{11}&A_{12}&0&0\\A_{21}&A_{22}&0&0\\0&0&A_{33}&A_{34}\\0&0&A_{43}&A_{44}\end{bmatrix}
  \]
 \end{block}
}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
```

In the following picture the Result is the output of this code. The desired one is what i want. I tried with `\begin{frame}[t]` but it didnt change something in the second column. (Ignore the green color of the block)
[image]

Any idea how to impliment that?

Comment: Have a look at `overlayarea`. You might also like `onlyenv` instead of those `\only<...>{....}` which makes the code very unreadable. BTW: Have a look at this blog texdev.net, a bit down in the right menu you can find the entries labeled `beamer`. That helped a lot on my slides.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `overlayarea` (as commented by dalief) or `overprint` environments for this. `overlayarea` is more flexible, hence preferred.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
 \frametitle{Buoy design}
  \begin{columns}
    \column{0.38\textwidth}
 \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
 \column{0.62\textwidth}
 \begin{overlayarea}{\linewidth}{\textheight}
  \begin{onlyenv}<1-3>
  \begin{block}{Equation of Motion}
 \[
 [\underline{M}+\underline{A}]\ddot{x}(t)+\underline{k}x(t)= F(t)
\]
\end{block}
\end{onlyenv}
\begin{onlyenv}<2>
\begin{block}{Mass Matrix M}
 \[
 \begin{bmatrix}M_{tot}&M_{tot}z_g&0&0\\M_{tot}z_g&I_{xx}&0&0\\0&0&M_{tot}&M_{tot}z_g\\0&0&M_{tot}z_g&I_{yy}\end{bmatrix}
 \]

 \end{block}
\end{onlyenv}
\begin{onlyenv}<3>
\begin{block}{Added Mass Matrix A}
   \[
     \begin{bmatrix}  A_{11}&A_{12}&0&0\\A_{21}&A_{22}&0&0\\0&0&A_{33}&A_{34}\\0&0&A_{43}&A_{44}\end{bmatrix}
  \]
 \end{block}
\end{onlyenv}
\end{overlayarea}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]